# Build IONIC on TEAMCITY failed

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

On my own instance of TEAMCITY server I want to build an Android application of Ionic.

Teamcity : On Windows server,
My build step on Powershell :

```
npm install
ionic cordova build android
```

The result : IONIC is not reconised as command

```
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1] ionic : Le terme ®ionic¯ n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou programme 
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1] 
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1] 
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1] ex‚cutable. V‚rifiez l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'accŠs existe, v‚rifiez que le chemin d'accŠs est correct 
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1] et r‚essayez.
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1] Au caractŠre C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell3528430019226856505.ps1:4 : 1
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1] + ionic cordova build android
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1] + ~~~~~
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ionic:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1]  
[11:44:19]  [Step 1/1] Process exited with code 0
```

If I run the same script directly in a powershell console in the same directory it's work.

I tried many approches but a still have the same issue.

Comment: What user is the TeamCity build agent running under? Is it one of the system accounts or a normal user account? Can you run the command prompt as that user and then try running the command again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution : I run on Administrator, in powershell mode.
Powershell build agent is run in a "sandbox" and I complete the path to read local node_module :

```
$currentPath = Convert-Path '.\node_modules\.bin\'
$env:Path += ";" + $currentPath
```